# software and hardware problems after upgrading from 18.04LTS to 20.04LTS

Tags: upgrade, 20.04

18.04 worked perfect in my System 76 laptop. I got a message that 20.04 LTS was available, so I figured, "Sure, why not?" I upgraded and my gscan2pdf would no longer work. In fact my printer wouldn't work either. I tried everything I knew, eventually deleted the printer and re-added it. It works only intermittently.

I don't know how to code nor how to use the terminal unless I'm told exactly what to type. I've upgraded and updated via terminal. I tried updating gscan2pdf, it made no difference.

I got some messages, but don't remember through which program, that my version is still using parts of 18.04 LTS. I would like to go back, despite thinking that problems will persist because of all the changing. So... can somebody tell me how to go back to 18.04 LTS?

Comment: You can go back to 18.04 if you wish. Or you can fix your 20.04. But you must clearly tell us which alternative you want to pursue.

Comment: I don't have confidence in this 20.04 LTS. It has so many problems! I had no problems with 18.04 LTS, not from day one to the day I upgraded. Yes, I would like to go back, despite thinking that problems will persist because of all the changing. So... can somebody tell me how to go back to 18.04 LTS?

Comment: There is no supported method of returning to an older release of Ubuntu. That requires a reinstall of 18.04.

Comment: OK. I'll reinstall. I have the usb stick that came with the computer from System 76. I opened it in terminal. It says: /media/patrick/Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS amd64$  Can you lead me through it from here?

Comment: Does a reinstall first delete everything already there?

Comment: An expert can reinstall without damaging any of your data. A reinstall is inherently risky. Backing up your data first is wise. When you are ready, don't *open* the USB. Boot from it, and follow the prompts.

Comment: I haven't been able to open the bios on my laptop. I pressed F12 repeatedly after pressing the power button, to no avail, so I can't boot from the stick.

Comment: Are you sure that the correct key is F12? Perhaps it's a different key.

Comment: It's F2 for bios, F7 for boot, but I didn't see an option to boot from USB port, at least not in language I use.

Comment: That what "boot" is for: To select your boot media. Try F7.

Comment: After pressing F7, as I said above, I did not see an option to boot from USB, at least not in languate I use. I don't know another way to make this statement.

Comment: Hmmm. Then I would go into F12 and see if your USB stick is detected.

Comment: I don't have the ability to write in a manner that relays that I am able to access the bios settings with either F2 or F7, but that once there, I cannot see an option for booting from one of my USB ports, at least not an option that mentions USB ports, using the words "USB ports". But it's a moot point, because I've decided to stick with 20.04 LTS because the printer is working more often than not, and the computer is shuttingn down properly more often than not, and I'll llive with it.  Going back to 18.04 LTS is more trouble to me than I want to exerience. I can also live without gscan2pdf.